# Get transaction data by its hash (Solidity)

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I need a method in my contract that receives a transaction (its hash) as a parameter and checks its data in the blockchain (sender, etc).Is there an object for transaction in Solidity? (Like one for address)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that this information is not accessible from a smart contract.